# Why is my Future<void> function that doesn't use an await required to be async?

Tags: flutter

In a flutter tutorial video on unit testing, there is a Future function that VSCode flags with

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Future', is a potentially non-nullable type.
> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Making the function async fixes the problem but it doesn't use any await statements. Can someone please explain to me what caused the error and why this is necessary?

```
@override
  Future<void> sendEmailVerification() {
    if (!isInitialized) throw NotInitializedException();
    if (_user == null) throw UserNotFoundException();
    const user = AuthUser(isEmailVerified: true);
    _user = user;
  }
```

Comment: As the error says, you aren't returning anything in your function (you are supposed to return a `Future`). (If it's not async and doesn't manually return a `Future<void>` either, why is its return type then a `Future<void>`? Should be `void`...) When you make the function `async` then from the outside world's perspective, the function _will_ return a `Future` even when you don't do that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function with a non-`void` return type must return *something*.

The `async` keyword does two things:

1. Enables the use of the `await` keyword.
2. Automatically transforms all `return` statements (whether explicit or implicit) to return a `Future`.  For example:

```dart
Future<int> f() async {
  return 42;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```dart
Future<int> f() {
  return Future.value(42);
}
```

and

```dart
Future<void> g() async {}
```

is equivalent to:

```dart
Future<void> g() {
  return Future<void>.value();
}
```